# How to read string until two consecutive spaces?

Tags: c, format, scanf, c-strings

A well known function of the `scanf()` functions is that you can pass a format to scan input according to this format.

For my case, I cannot seem to find a solution searching [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) and [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ccrug00/sscanf.htm) documentation.

I have a string (`sInput`) as the following:

```
#something VAR1 this is a constant string     //some comment
```

Where `VAR1` is meant to be the name of the constant string `this is a constant`.

Now I am scanning this string like this:

```
if(sscanf(sInput, "%*s %s %s", paramname, constantvalue) != 2)
   //do something
```

And of course, when I output `paramname` and `constantvalue` I get:

```
VAR1
this
```

But I would like to have `constantvalue` to contain the string until two consecutive spaces are found (so it would contain the part `this is a constant string`).

So therefore I tried:

```
sscanf(sInput, "%*s %s %[^(  )]s", paramname, constantvalue)
sscanf(sInput, "%*s %s %[^  ]s", paramname, constantvalue)
```

But without luck. Is there a way to achieve my goal with `sscanf()`? Or should I implement another way of storing the string?

Comment: Do you *have* to use [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)? And remember that the `"%["` format is not a regular expression format, it just lists a *set* of characters.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No I do not have to but it seemed the easiest to me.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with `sscanf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`scanf` family of functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) are good for simple parsing, but not for more complicated things like you seem to do.

You *could* probably solve it by using e.g. [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) to find the comment starter `"//"`, terminate the string there, and then remove trailing [space](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace).

Comment: Well this seems to answer my question, and thank you for the example. Let's build!